# Order of Evaluation - Merge Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

In what order does evaluation happen in oracle merge queries?

For example:

```sql
MERGE INTO SCEHMA.TABLE updtab
USING (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_VIEW) fromtab
ON (updtab.key = fromtab.key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
  updtab.field_1 = case when (updtab.field_1 is null) then fromtab.val_1 end,
  updtab.field_2 = case when (updtab.field_1 is null) then fromtab.val_2 end;
```

Will both cases for field_1 is null be evaluated right away or will each set execute in sequence and the second for field_2 always fail since field_1 will no longer be null after the first set line?

SQL standard is I believe that the selection always happens first, but this is within the update step no? Oracles documentation is unclear and had me wondering.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is happening within a single statement, the `MERGE`. Oracle [*"always enforces statement-level read consistency, which guarantees that data returned by a single query is committed and consistent for a single point in time."*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT121). In this case the point in time is the time at which the statement was "opened" - the time it began execution.

This means that `field_1` is seen by *all* parts of the `MERGE` statement to be the same data until the statement has terminated. `field_1` is evaluated once and each update is executed as if the data does not change.

Within a single *transaction*, you're correct. In the default read committed isolation level a non-repeatable read is possible. If a `SELECT` statement is re-run and another transaction has committed data then the data read by your first transaction might be different. The `MERGE` is a statement, and not a transaction.